# How to attach ACR from different Subscription to AKS?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, devops, azure-aks, acr

can anyone know how to attach ACR from different subscriptions to AKS in Azure?
I am looking for any info about that, alas I've found only a topic https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/243 where someone said that this is fixed but unfortunately there's no info how to achieve that?

Comment: it shouldn't matter if its from the same subscription or not (unless cross-tenants), you are probably doing something wrong, can you show what you are doing?

Comment: The ACR is also in the different resource group. I'm writing `az aks update --name my-aks --resource-group my-aks-resource-group --attach-acr acr-id`

Comment: doesnt matter, whats the error you are getting?

Comment: The resource with name 'id' and type 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries' could not be found in subscription 'subs name (subs id)'

Comment: well, that means exactly that, its not there

Comment: Yep... I've provided ACR with some additional char at the end. Simple and stupid. But many thanks to you @4c74356b41 for help and confirming that this is possible. Hopes that someone will take advantage from this question. Best regards!

Comment: @4c74356b41 it shouldn't matter, but it does: `> az aks update --attach-acr ACR-name --name AKS-name --resource-group Resource-Group-name  
The resource with name 'ACR-name' and type 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries' could not be found in subscription 'Subscription-name (subsription-ID)'`. It clearly shows that by default Azure looks for the resource group and the ACR in the same subscription.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in this case the answer was to provide the proper input (typo in the ACR ID).

Comment: For anyone else also having this issue here is an example of the command I used:
`az aks update -g "Some-AKS-RG" -n "Some-Cluster" --attach-acr "/subscriptions/<SOME SUB ID>/resourceGroups/<Some RG Name>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/<Some ACR Name>`

The initial slash is very important apparently

Comment: That is the real answer. The proper ACR path can be obtained by querying the ACR resource with `az resource list --name <ACR name>`. The path will be the value of the "id" key.

Comment: It says: `ERROR: Subscription '[MASKED]' not found. Check the spelling and casing and try again.`

Comment: So I had to give the Service Princpal access to that susbcription. Works fine now.