# How to attach a second ACR to my AKS cluster?

Tags: azure-aks, azure-container-service

The document describes how to attach an ACR to existing AKS cluster, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration

- How do I attach a second ACR to my AKS cluster?
- The ACR has a different subscription.

attach the first ACR:

```
az account set --subscription acr-subscription
$ACR_ID = $(az acr show --name $ACRName  --resource-group $ACRResourceGroupName --query "id" --output tsv)
az account set --subscription aks-subscription
az aks update --name cluster-name --resource-group cluster-resource --attach-acr $ACR_ID
```

Comment: are you getting an error on the second attach ?

Comment: Also is your cluster using a service principal or managed service indentity (MSI?)

Comment: I did not receive a error, thanks for feedback @djsly , it works as you describe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on this StackOverFLow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60210403/how-to-attach-acr-from-different-subscription-to-aks), this should work as long as your ID is in the right format

```
echo $(az acr show --name $name --resource-group $resourcegroup --query "id" --output tsv)
```

returns the right format and value.

the code associated with `--attach-acr` simply add the acrpull IAM role to the ACR resource using the identity_profile ID associated to the kubernetes cluster.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/a9fe6167381b53dac19a3007f726adf27b64f28b/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py#L559

there is no where in the code where it checks if another ACR was previous attached to the AKS resource. Therefore, it should be able to set the role assignment directly for multiple instances.

this should work properly

```
az account set --subscription acr-subscription
$ACR_ID = $(az acr show --name $ACRName  --resource-group $ACRResourceGroupName --query "id" --output tsv)

az account set --subscription acr2-subscription
$ACR2_ID = $(az acr show --name $ACR2Name  --resource-group $ACR2ResourceGroupName --query "id" --output tsv)

az account set --subscription aks-subscription
az aks update --name cluster-name --resource-group cluster-resource --attach-acr $ACR_ID
az aks update --name cluster-name --resource-group cluster-resource --attach-acr $ACR2_ID
```

Comment: I get the message:AAD role propagation done but it is still not working for me.. any clue?

Comment: I am also getting 
```
AAD role propagation done[############################################]  100.0000%
``` still not working for me

Comment: In my case the issue was that I was not owner of subscriptions.