# Attach an aks (azure k8s cluster) to ACR in deferenet subscription

Tags: azure, registry, azure-aks, subscription, acr

i have 2 Susbscription first is called Prod and the 2nd is called  Non-Prod.

the non prod subscription containes an aks "ttr-aks" and i want to attach it to the ACR which exists into the prod subscription

i am running following command to do the attachment after assign the role pullArc in the ACR

az aks update --name ttr-aks --resource-group ttr-res-grp --attach-acr myacr
and get the following Error

ERROR: The resource with name '3fceXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' and type 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries' could not be found in subscription 'NON-PROD (e788173sssssssssssssssssssss)'.

i google it and didnt find an solution for this issue
chant gpt is not helping too much

Comment: Use your [resource ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/container-registry-get-resource-id?view=azs-2306) of ACR. In command try to update the resource id at the end --attach-acr <ResourceID>

Comment: hi 
thank you for answering , still have the issue and i tried all combinations , nothing is working

Comment: @DawodKabha did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960796/how-to-attach-a-second-acr-to-my-aks-cluster

Answer (score 0):

To attach your `ttr-aks` AKS to an ACR in different subscription make use of below steps:

Select the AKS cluster that you want to attach the ACR to. In your case it is `ttr-aks`

***In Aks cluster -> Networking tab under Container registries -> Add*** -> choose the subscription which you want to attach to your AKS. In your case prod/non-prod.

[image]

The AKS cluster will now be attached to your desired ACR. Make sure that the ACR is in the same region as the AKS cluster.

Also, you can try this [so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960796/how-to-attach-a-second-acr-to-my-aks-cluster) by djsly

***Reference***:

[Integrate Azure Container Registry with Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) - Azure Kubernetes Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration?tabs=azure-cli)

Comment: Thank you , but i am looking for cli command , i am creating a script for automate cluster raising up

Comment: check this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960796/how-to-attach-a-second-acr-to-my-aks-cluster)

Comment: Use this comment : az aks create -n myAKSCluster -g myResourceGroup --generate-ssh-keys --attach-acr /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/myContainerRegistryResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/myContainerRegistry

Comment: az aks create -n daw-aks -g my-res-grp --generate-ssh-keys --attach-acr /subscriptions/xxxx-5bd8692d16e0/resourceGroups/myContainerRegistryResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/myContainerRegistry
ERROR: The resource with name 'C:/Users/Dawodk/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/subscriptions/xxxx-9715-5bd8692d16e0/resourceGroups/myContainerRegistryResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/myContainerRegistry' and type 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries' could not be found in subscription 'NON-PROD (e7881732-06db-44cf-9715-5bd8692d16e0)'.